# Parcelable with further operations in getter methods

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Parcelable on my "Evento" class.

Problem is, all the tutorials and questions I found online have no operations done inside the getter method of their class, but mine do, since I need some conversion with dates and forming a list of dates.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to do those operations inside the getter methods and then parcelize the class (I tried it somehow in the code below), or should I do those operations outside of the Evento class?

Here's the code:

```
class Evento implements Parcelable{
    private String titolo, titolomin, titolocor, inizio, datastring, datastringcor, fine, luogo, primapartedata, secondapartedata, cat;
    private Date datacor, datafinecor, datafine, dataLDinizio, dataLDfine;
    private int id, categoria;
    private String link;
    private SimpleDateFormat dataorig, dforminizioita, dformfineita, dforminizioitac, sdflistdate;
    private List<Date> durata = new ArrayList<>();
    private Calendar calendar;

    public Evento(int id, String titolo, String inizio, String fine, int categoria, String link, String luogo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titolo = titolo;
        this.inizio = inizio;
        this.fine = fine;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.link = link;
        this.luogo = luogo;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitolo() {
        titolomin = titolo.toLowerCase();
        if (titolomin.contains("mat 1")) {
            titolocor = "Matwork 1";} 
        else if (titolomin.contains("mat 2")) {
            titolocor = "Matwork 2";
        [...]
// Cutting it here, just a bunch of other similar lines


        return titolocor;
    }

    public String getDataString() {
        dataorig = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            datacor = dataorig.parse(inizio);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        [...]

//Same as above

        return datastring;
    }

    public Date getDataorig() {
        dataorig = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        try {
            datacor = dataorig.parse(inizio);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return datacor;
    }

    public Date getfine() {
        dataorig = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        try {
            datafine = dataorig.parse(fine);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return datafine;
    }

    public List<Date> getListDate() {
        sdflistdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        [...]
//same

        return durata;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        switch (categoria) {
            case 1:
               [...]
// Same
        return cat;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getLuogo() {
        return luogo;
    }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeInt(this.id);
        parcel.writeString(getTitolo()); // I guess this won't work?
        parcel.writeString(this.datastring); // This should return void, i think?
//Maybe i should redo the above operations before writing into the parcel? Dunno.
        parcel.writeList(getListDate());
        parcel.writeString(this.link);
        parcel.writeString(this.luogo);
}

protected Evento(Parcel p) {
        this.id = p.readInt();
        this.titolocor = p.readString();
        this.datastring = p.readString();
        durata = new ArrayList<>();
        p.readList(durata,Evento.class.getClassLoader());
        this.link = p.readString();
        this.luogo = p.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Evento createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Evento(in);
    }

    public Evento[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Evento[size];
    }
};


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by myself, i changed the getter methods, now they only return the plain variable, such as:

```
public String getTitolo() {
    return titolo;
}
```

This way the Object is parcelable without further issues. All the operations that were inside the getter method, i just created another class and called it when necessary.